# Insert action after Woocomerce Completed Order Email is sent out

Tags: filter, woocommerce, hook, action

I want to accomplish the following:

With the Woocomerce Completed Order Email a pdf is generated and sent out as attachment. After the Email is sent, the pdf is deleted on the server.

I achieved the first part with the woocommerce_email_attachments Filter like this.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_ticket_pdf_to_email', 10,  3);
```

Now for security reasons I want to delete the pdf that was generated on the server AFTER the Email is sent out.

I found the Action 'woocommerce_order_status_completed’ that could be hooked into, but this is not called if I resend the Completed Order Email from the admin backend.

Is there some hook or filter or action that is called to send out the Emails in Woocomerce. Or after the emails are sent?

There I would like to call a function that deletes those pdfs again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The emails are triggered with a default priority of 10. Therefore, I presume that you could call your function with a higher/later priority and it would be fired *after* the email was sent.

If you *re-send* an order email from the admin you can use the [`woocommerce_after_resend_order_email`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/85faaf8b7732f0ee477af479b9a05582dbe0e814/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-actions.php#L134) hook. This gets passed an `$order` object so you can't quite attach the exact same function to both.

Here's how I would start:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'delete_pdf', 20 );
function delete_pdf( $order_id ){
    // do your thing to delete the file
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_resend_order_email', 'after_resend', 10, 2 );
function after_resend( $order, $action ){
    if( $action == 'customer_completed_order' ){
        delete_pdf( $order->id );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! The woocommerce_after_resend_order_email action works perfect, but the   woocommerce_after_resend_order_email  with priority 20 doesn't work. It's not fired afterwards....any idea how I could tweak this so that it actually deletes the folder?